# How to define a Function in VBS with Default Valued parameter

Tags: vbscript

How to define a Function in VBS with Default Valued parameter?

I had tried many different ways, nothing seems working

```
Function Calculate(operator1 = 20, operator2 = 30)
 ' logic goes here
End Function
```

```
Function Calculate(Optional ByVal operator1 As Int = 20, Optional ByVal operator2 As Int = 30)
 ' logic goes here
End Function
```

Comment: As pointed out in [the duplicate target](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1888947/692942) you could use an `Array()` to pass the arguments or use null-checking inside the procedure. Ref [Optional Arguments in VBScript](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/071801-1.shtml).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think VBScript supports 'Optional'.  So you might have create a custom class like so:

```
class CustomClass
    Dim operator1
    Dim operator2

    function Calculate
        'set default values here
        if IsEmpty(operator1) then operator1 = 20
        if IsEmpty(operator2) then operator2 = 30

        msgbox operator1
        msgbox operator2
    end function
end class

Dim myCustomClass : Set myCustomClass = new CustomClass

'override values here if required
myCustomClass.operator1 = 11
myCustomClass.operator2 = 12

myCustomClass.Calculate

Set myCustomClass = Nothing
```

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of work for an optional argument, as [the duplicate target](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1888947/692942) points out you could use an `Array()` to pass the arguments or use null-checking inside the procedure. Ref [Optional Arguments in VBScript](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/071801-1.shtml)